# Handsontable inside of fixed width and height segment

Tags: height, width, overflow, handsontable

I have a 'handsontable' table inside of bootstrap section-body. 
When I double-click on A1 cell once, and then scroll right, another scrollbars appears inside the original content.
It looks like a Render issue.

```js
(function(){

 angular
  .module('mainApp',[])
  .controller('mainController', mainController)
 ;

 mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

 function mainController ($scope) {

  var container = document.getElementById('example');
      
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(25, 25),
   minSpareRows: 1,
   rowHeaders: true,
   colHeaders: true,
   stretchH: "all"
  });

  container.style.height = 400 + 'px';
  container.style.overflow = 'auto';
 }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="mainApp">  
  <div  ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class='container'>
      <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8'>
        <div class='row'>
          <br>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div id='example'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfilddle out of it? I'm not seeing this issue.

Comment: ah ok, it seems like you have conflicting css. It's likely something in the panel css is screwing with this table.